# Accessing content of news using jsoup

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, webview, jsoup

I am connecting to a website from where i take the news and put them in a list. When i click on the news(its title) i want to go to another page where i can see the content of the news. I am doing this using jsoup. Logcat doesn't give me any error but the app crushes when i am clicking on the titles.

Here is my activity:

public class TargetActivity1 extends Activity {
    ListView lista;

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.web);

    Parse parsing = new Parse();
    parsing.execute();

}

private class Parse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String desc;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            // Connect to the web site
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(
                    "http://www.polimi.it/en/news/").get();
            // Using Elements to get the Meta data
            Elements description = document.select("div .news-list-item a");
            // Locate the content attribute
            desc = description.attr("href");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Set description into TextView
        WebView txtdesc = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);

        txtdesc.addView(txtdesc);

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(desc));
        startActivity(i);
        txtdesc.removeAllViews();

    }

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                MainActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

        return true;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: if your app crashes, you should have something in logcat

Comment: Yeah true. it says: no activity found to handle intent {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat= (the website from where i am parsing)}. so the problem is with Intent but i don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Parse` class is wrong, it should be like this:

```
private class Parse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String desc = "";
        try {
            // Connect to the web site
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(
                    "http://www.polimi.it/en/news/").get();
            // Using Elements to get the Meta data
            Elements description = document.select("div .news-list-item a");
            // Locate the content attribute
            desc = description.attr("href");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return desc;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // Set description into TextView
        WebView txtdesc = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);

        txtdesc.addView(txtdesc); // adding txtdesc to txtdesc? it's wrong, bug

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(result));
        startActivity(i);

        txtdesc.removeAllViews();

    }
}
```

Please read about AsyncTask here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. Result from `doInBackground` can be passed to `onPostExecute` as above. Also please a note, that you are trying to add a view to itself, I've commented it.